# Extracting information depending on user input from a dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

I have the following information from a [.json](http://www.futbin.com/api?term=paul%20pogba) loaded and stored in a variable `Data`:

```
Data = [
    {u'rating': u'89', u'rare': u'1', u'name': u'Pogba', u'club_image': u'/content/fifa17/img/clubs/11.png', u'image': u'/content/fifa17/img/players/195864.png', u'rare_type': u'3', u'version': u'IF', u'full_name': u'Pogba', u'position': u'CDM', u'id': u'15073', u'nation_image': u'/content/fifa17/img/nation/18.png'},
    {u'rating': u'89', u'rare': u'1', u'name': u'Pogba', u'club_image': u'/content/fifa17/img/clubs/11.png', u'image': u'/content/fifa17/img/players/195864.png', u'rare_type': u'21', u'version': u'OTW', u'full_name': u'Pogba', u'position': u'CM', u'id': u'15091', u'nation_image': u'/content/fifa17/img/nation/18.png'},
    {u'rating': u'88', u'rare': u'1', u'name': u'Pogba', u'club_image': u'/content/fifa17/img/clubs/11.png', u'image': u'/content/fifa17/img/players/195864.png', u'rare_type': u'1', u'version': u'Normal', u'full_name': u'Pogba', u'position': u'CM', u'id': u'78', u'nation_image': u'/content/fifa17/img/nation/18.png'}
]
```

I'd like to extract the information depending on the `rating` of the player inputted by the user, only if *another rating exists*. *EDIT* : *By this, I mean that if only one line was present, i.e. 1 rating, there would be no need to carry out the process.*

For example, if the user inputted: `88`, it would return/print:

```
{u'rating': u'88', u'rare': u'1', u'name': u'Pogba', u'club_image': u'/content/fifa17/img/clubs/11.png', u'image': u'/content/fifa17/img/players/195864.png', u'rare_type': u'1', u'version': u'Normal', u'full_name': u'Pogba', u'position': u'CM', u'id': u'78', u'nation_image': u'/content/fifa17/img/nation/18.png'}
```

From my minimal knowledge, I am aware that I must use dictionaries, but am unaware of how to do so. However, I am currently in the following stage in my attempts:

```
player_dict = {Data}
player_info = player_dict.get(user_input)
if player_info:
    for item in player_info:
        player_info = item
```

^ *This doesn't seem to work at all.*

Comment: What do you mean by "only if another rating exists" ?

Comment: @wim If there was only 1 rating e.g. 88 was the only one, then in the .json only the following would be present: `{u'rating': u'88', u'rare': u'1', u'name': u'Pogba', u'club_image': u'/content/fifa17/img/clubs/11.png', u'image': u'/content/fifa17/img/players/195864.png', u'rare_type': u'1', u'version': u'Normal', u'full_name': u'Pogba', u'position': u'CM', u'id': u'78', u'nation_image': u'/content/fifa17/img/nation/18.png'}` so there would be no need to carry out the whole process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers don't include your requirement that data should only be returned if the `rating` appears in `Data` once only.

```
# First iterate over Data and count how many times that rating appears
counter = {}
for item in Data:
    rating = item['rating']
    counter[rating] = counter.get(rating, 0) + 1

# Now build a dict that uses rating as a key and the whole dataset with  
# that rating as a value. Include only ratings that appeared once in Data
cleaned_dict = {item['rating']: item for item in Data if counter.get(item['rating']) == 1}

query = raw_input('Enter rating:')

if cleaned_dict.get(query):
    print "FOUND"
    print cleaned_dict.get(query)
else:
    print "Not found, no need to process further"
```

Explanation:
In the first `for` loop, we build a dictionary of `{rating: frequency}`. The line `counter[rating] = counter.get(rating, 0) + 1` says that if the `rating` isn't in the dictionary, give that rating a default count of `0` and immediately add `1` to it. i.e. it appears once. If, however, later in the `for` loop we find that rating again, we get the value stored against that rating and add `1` to it. You could also use the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) object for this but I've found that usually to be slower to `get()`.

In `cleaned_dict` we use a dictionary comprehension to build a new set of data only if that rating appeared once in `Data`. We store the whole raw data against a key of just the `rating`. This allows fast lookup on user input.

Finally, we take user input and look for the rating in our dictionary. If the rating is not a key in `cleaned_data` then we get `None`, which is falsey, so `if cleaned_dict.get(query):` is interpreted as `False`.

EDIT based on comments:

```
cleaned_dict = {}
for item in Data:
    rating = item['rating']
    is_in_dict = cleaned_dict.get(rating)
    if is_in_dict:
        position = item['position']
        cleaned_dict[rating][position] = item
    else:
        sub_dict = {}
        sub_dict[item['position']] = item
        cleaned_dict[rating] = sub_dict

rating_input = raw_input('Enter rating:')
check_rating = cleaned_dict.get(rating_input)
if check_rating:
    position_input = raw_input('Enter position:')
    if check_rating.get(position_input):
        print check_rating.get(position_input)
    else:
        print "Record of rating, but not position"
else:
    print "No record of rating {}".format(rating_input)
```

Comment: @BenF97 you're welcome :). To be fair to the others, I did happen to see the edited question first, and it wasn't overly clear prior to the edit.

Comment: Just tested it out and adapted it to my full source code! Works fantastic! I do have another question if you don't mind me asking. In some scenarios, the `rating` can be the same, if that is the case, could I adapt what you provided me, so that if there are matches of the same rating, the user must input the `position` to narrow down and then the line would be picked out. Would that be manageable by simply adapting what you provided me or would I have to incorporate something else? Thanks.

Comment: @BenF97 yes, you could do this, but it is beyond the scope of this question so should be raised as a new question. In essence though, you would only have to iterate through `Data` once. If `rating` is not found, append `item` to a new list and store against the rating. If the same rating is found a second time, `append` the new `item` to the list stored against that rating. If you try and are unable to make sense of that, open a new question. The same principles apply, but knowing "position" beforehand evades me atm. How could you know that for any generic match?

Comment: @BenF97 Aha, so `position` is another entry there. My answer would constitute the same as I described above, but then you'd have to iterate through the all the results returned against a matching `rating`. There could well be a cool way of storing the index to reduce time complexity from that, but it might make the code hard to read.

Comment: Haha, Okay, I'll give it my best shot. Probably won't go very far though - Sounds pretty complicated! :D

Comment: @BenF97 Actually, if there are multiple entries for each `rating` but they have a unique `position` values (for each value of `rating` they are associated with) then rather than build a list, store a nested dictionary inside the main dictionary: the outer dictionary maps `rating` to a second, inner, dictionary that maps `position` to a unique record. It's getting a bit tough to answer in comments. Have a proper go though before raising a new question; you'll learn more that way :)

Comment: Thanks, Sounds too complex for my current 'bank of knowledge' of Python :D But I'll give it a go.

Comment: @BenF97 any answer to your follow-on question is likely to only be useful to you as you don't yet know the concepts involved. Please see my edit to this answer, which addresses your next question. You should take some time to understand what's going on.

Comment: Hi @roganjosh I've been going over the amazing edited code you've provided and helped me with. But I'm honestly struggling to understand how it works the way it does. If you ever have some time, I'd greatly appreciate a brief explanation as I'm fairly new to Python, but trying my best.

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case, you need to loop over your values and compare the one that has been input to the ones you already have, right?

So `player_dict` is a list of dictionaries, and every dictionary contains properties about a player, of which `rating` is one.
Also, let's say that `player_info` is the user-inputted rating, like `88`.

```
for player_dict in player_dict:
    try:
         if player_dict['rating']==player_info:
              return player_dict
    except KeyError:
         print 'there is no key called rating in this dict!'
```

Comment: Thanks, Although it doesn't seem to work. I've tried the following: http://hastebin.com/ozaqufuqum.py But I get a syntax error: 'return' outside function

Comment: Bug: `for player_dict in player_dict:`

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
[record for record in Data if record.get("rating") == ratingWeWant]
```

where `ratingWeWant` is the rating you are searching for.

That code will produce list of records from data that have specified rating, eg:

`[{u'rating': u'88', u'club_image': u'/content/fifa17/img/clubs/11.png', u'image': u'/content/fifa17/img/players/195864.png', u'full_name': u'Pogba', u'id': u'78', u'nation_image': u'/content/fifa17/img/nation/18.png', u'rare': u'1', u'name': u'Pogba', u'rare_type': u'1', u'version': u'Normal', u'position': u'CM'}]`

for data in your post.

Also, because we use `.get()` method of dict, we don't have to worry about exceptions.

Comment: Probably some unicode-string/string/integer mismatch in your code. [Here](http://ideone.com/smwvus) is proof that it works.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called a "lookup". Given a key (u'88', or other rating), you want a value (the dictionary where 'rating' is u'88'). A list object, like you currently have the dictionaries stored in, is not very good for such lookups, because you have to go through each index in the list, compare the rating to the key, and then return the dictionary (if it exists at all).

```
key = u'88'
for d in Data:
    if d['rating'] == key:
        print d
```

Consider what happens when you have a large amount of dictionaries stored in that list. What if none of the dictionaries have a rating equal to the key? You pass through a large number of dictionaries, checking for equalities, only to have none exist. This is wasted computations.

As you know, python's `dict` type is very-well suited for lookups. If you had a dictionary that looked like

```
Data_dict = {u'88': {u'rare': u'1', u'name': u'Pogba', ...},
             u'89': {u'rare': u'1', u'name': u'Pogba', ...} }
```

then you could quickly see if the key u'88' is in that dataset.

```
if u'88' in Data_dict:
    print Data_dict[u'88']
```

To make such a dictionary, from your current Data as a list:

```
Data_dict = {val[u'rating']: val for val in Data}
```

Comment: Cheers Logan! If I was to want to replace `u'88'` with `u'x'`, `x` being the `user_input`, how would I go round doing that? Thanks.

Comment: I've tried: key = `'u'(user_input)'` but it doesn't work

Comment: If user_input is a unicode string, just use that directly as the key. If it is an int, interpret it as unicode `unicode(str(user_input), 'utf-8')`.